# Sum from 1 to n, 2 to n, ... n in python

Tags: python, sum

I was trying to get a series of sum from 1 to n, 2 to n, ..., and n

For example, if n=5, then the result should be
15
14
12
9
5

Please comment for the code below. I can't figure out what's wrong.

```
n=int(input())
sum=0
m=0
factorial=1

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    factorial *= i
    sum=factorial-m
    print(sum)
```

Comment: Your code prints the factorial of i for i from 1 to n...

Comment: A hint: factorial is concerned with products, your problem only involves sums. So I'd be surprised if the solution contained any `*`. Maybe google "triangle numbers".

Comment: Are you sure this is the code you attempted? This code looks like it's for calculating factorial (even the variable name says it's factorial), which is somewhat irrelevant to your original question.

Comment: Wow~ Why so many downvotes? This question is not so bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reasonably simple approach:

```
n = 5
s = sum(range(n+1))
for i in range(n):
    s -= i
    print(s)

15
14
12
9
5
```

Comment: Thank you, this simply works. This is what I exactly wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confused with the logic of your problem, but if you want to get the sum from 1 to n you can do the following:

```
import numpy as np
series = np.arange(1, n)
for i in range(series.size + 1):
    print(series[:i].sum())
```

if n = 5, the output will be: `0, 1, 3, 6, 10`