# Printing reverse Sum of numbers from 1 to n

Tags: python

I am learning python and I am really struggling to figure out how to write this code where I get an input `a` that is bigger than 1 and the output should look like this:

Sum from 1 to a
Sum from 2 to a
Sum from 3 to a
.....
a

E.g. for 5, the output should be:

```
15
14
12
9
5
```

This is what I have so far

```
a=int(input())
for t in range(a):
    b=a*(a+1)/2
    b=b-t
    print(a+t)
```

I cant seem to figure out how to subtract it from reverse and how to print each results in the process

Comment: What do you mean "how to subtract it from reverse?" Also what is "n" that you want to print? Can you give an example of expected output for a=4?

Comment: Exlected output for a=4 would look like this

Comment: This should be in this order 10 9 7 4

Comment: For a=5 it should be 15 14 12 9 5

Comment: I knew this question was awkwardly familiar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52991350/sum-from-1-to-n-2-to-n-n-in-python/52991513#52991513 You don't happen to be in the same coding class ;)

Answer (score 3):

The following will work:

```
a = int(input())
# s = sum(range(1, a+1))
s = a * (a+1) // 2

for t in range(1, a+1):
    print(s)
    s -= t
```

Produces for `a = 5`:

```
15
14
12
9
5
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of only subtracting the counter `t`, you need to subtract the sum of 1 ... `t`.
Otherwise your code does not need to be changed, I just added the forcing to int.

```
a = int(input())
for t in range(a):
    b=a*(a+1)//2
    c=t*(t+1)//2
    b=b-c
    print(b)
```

Output:

```
15
14
12
9
5
```